# Trying to calculate a percentage rank to each row based on type(which is a column with around 10 unqiue string)

Tags: python, pandas, rank

I have a data frame of over a million rows with a sample structure like this:

> **ID Type Value1 Value2... (more columns)**
>
> **1  A    20    4 ...**
>
> **2  A    30    5 ...**
>
> **3  B    14    7...**
>
> **4  B    12    9...**
>
> **.....**

I hope I could get

> **ID Type Value1 Value2 Pct_Rank_based_on_Value1 ... (more columns)**
>
> **1  A    20    4  0.107 ...**
>
> **2  A    30    5  0.021 ...**
>
> **3  B    14    7  0.201 ...**
>
> **4  B    12    9  0.875 ...**

**.....**

> rank should be in decreasing order of value. The max should have a value near 0.001

And for clarification, my purpose is to create a new column which is the percentage ranking of a row's Value1 (which is a column of discrete numbers) within itsType (which is a column of strings, only 10 unique values).

For row 1, ID is 1, Type is A, Value is 20, I'd like to compute its pct rank of Value1 within those rows whose Type is also A.

1. I have checked a few post's implementations and I am thinking of using

   df['Pct_Rank'] = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby("Type").index.get_level_values('Value1').rank(pct = True)

   But I'm not sure if it is correct.
2. I thought about create sub-dataframes with each types and sort them based on Value1, but how to search the position for each row's Values in its corresponding type? After that I could write a func and apply to each row, computing its pct rank by

> increment_type_A = 1/lengthA
>
> ....
>
> if type == A:
>
> pct_rank = increment_typeA * position_in_its_type
>
> .......

By the way, is there any parameters to set the pct? like the precision? I want something like 0.001 at least.

### Updates

I just reformatted my sample. The table was messed up after I select them and choose "bold".

Just edited to clarify that has more than 1 number-valued column. And Value1 is not the first column with number-value.

Comment: It's not that clear to me what you're starting off with - any chance you could write a minimal working example?

Comment: I just reformatted my sample. The table was messed up after I select them and choose "bold".

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly, this should work:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame([['A', 20, 1], ['A', 30, 2], ['B', 14, 1], ['B', 12, 6]], columns=['Type', 'Value1', 'Value2'])
df['pct_rank'] = df.groupby('Type').rank(axis=0, pct=True, ascending=False)['Value1']
```

Comment: I’m not sure if it would work since I got not only Value1 but also Value2, 3, etc. I want to rank based on Value1. For the first row, could look like ID =1, Type = A, Value1 = 20, Value2 =5, Value3 = abcd.

Comment: Please edit your question so it includes a small example of a DataFrame similar to the one you have, along with the output you expect.

Comment: @Paladinnn I've edited my answer to it answers what I think you're asking

Comment: Sorry I didn’t put it more clear in previous edition. I didn’t intend to waste your time. Just edited. Thank you for answering my question. Really appreciated.

Comment: That's fine. Does my current answer work? If not, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - specifically, the part which says "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem"